# Can't find namespace on host

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

I have a ASP.NET application that just works fine on localhost, but when I up to host I get an error:

> The type or namespace name 'Nini' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have no idea how to fix this. The dll was added by using 'add reference' on VS 08 and the Nini.dll file was uploaded in bin folder.

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using TFS to deploy to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Try including the namespace by using statement in your code wherever you are using this DLL.

Comment: can you share some more of your code ... also can you check what path you have given while adding reference?

Comment: All code what I share is `using Nini.Config;` from the page where the error happen..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1. The DLL is being copied over to the web server.  You can check this by navigating to the site via FTP, or just going to where the files are deployed to (whether it be on your company's network, an external website/web app, etc.).
2. If you're using a web deployment utility, like within Visual Studio for example, click on the DLL in the solution explorer, press F4 (for "properties"), and make sure that Copy Local is set to True.  If not, set it to True, then try deploying again.